Find Cipher suites used for Custom Domain Name in AWS
I have a Custom Domain Name configured in API Gateway in AWS. I can see it is using TLS 1.2. I need to check the cipher suite it is using.
I am not sure how to check the cipher suites. I can see the certificate attached with it and the algorithm too but from where do I get the ciphers used?
